# What is it about functions like tzset() and ctime_r() that requires the locale to be constant to be thread safe

Tags: c, posix

The Linux man pages say, taking tzset() as an example, that

> tzset()   │ Thread safety │ MT-Safe env locale

which means that if both env and locale don't change during its execution, it is thread-safe; otherwise not.  It's clear to me why the environment changing could affect this, but it I do not understand how the locale changing would.

If this function were locale-dependent, it should say which category it depends on, like strftime() depends on LC_TIME, and its man page says so.

tzset() sets three externals, including tzname.  The encoding of that name is unspecified.  Posix 2008 says it shall not exceed a certain number of bytes in length.

Answer (score 0):

Per the standard this is incorrect; as you've noted, nothing about `tzset` or `ctime_r` depends on locale. The man page is either incorrect or documenting a non-conforming behavior in glibc that causes it to be unsafe under change to locale. To get to the bottom of this you'd need to either read the source or file a bug report against the documentation and hope somebody else is willing to do the digging.

Comment: The man page is still the same after 8 years.

Comment: I looked at the source; glibc is using things like isdigit, strtol, which have locale dependencies; so that may be where it comes from.  The only single byte locale I could easily find tat had a second set of digits was the Thai 8859 one

Comment: @khw: isdigit doesn't depend on locale. It's required to be exactly the 10 C basic character set digits.

Comment: I recall seeing somewhere that a 2nd set of digits was permissible in a locale, but I can't find that now

Comment: @khw: The locale can have alt digits used for alt time formatting with `strftime` and special modifiers, and to be optionally accepted by `strtol` etc, but they are not part of the `isdigit` class. It's required by ISO C to consist of nothing but the 10 values `'0'` through `'9'`.